# Setting up Magento 1.4 locally, MAMP

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, mamp, magento-1.4

As the title says, I am trying to set up an old 1.4 Magento installation locally with MAMP.

**Things i did so far:**

- Download entire website
- Import Database
- Change unsecure and secure base_url
- Change database user information in local.xml
- Delete everything inside the var folder
- Set PHP version to 5.3

A fresh install of 1.4 Magento works fine on my system.

All I get is a Magento error screen saying *"There has been an error processing your request"*

The error messages generated to the var/report folder are exe files, and return something like

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sandbergdesign/var/report/624953303320: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sandbergdesign/var/report/624953303320: line 17:`#16 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}'
logout

When clicked

Comment: Look into the folder var/report to see which error occurred.

Comment: @SanderH Please update your question with the errors in the error report.

Comment: @Muk Does the error message make any sense?

Comment: @SanderH Is it complete text of error report?

Comment: @Muk Yes, nothing more is output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it up and running.

I decided to download a fresh Magento 1.9, and installed it using the OLD database, the one from the Magento 1.4 site.

I also had to truncate the following tables in the DB:

- Truncate all log_ tables
- Truncate report_event, report_compared_product_index, and report_viewed_product_index

After truncating I could complete the installation process, and can proceed to implement the old theme, test functionality, etc.